# scala: overriding equals of basic types

Tags: java, scala, equals, equality

I've defined a wrapper class:

```
class Wrapper[T](private val value: T)
```

and I want to make sure that w(v1) == v2 and v2 == w(v1) iff v1 == v2. The first part is easy because you can override equals method of Wrapper class. But the problem is the other way around, making 5 == Wrapper(5) return true for example, achieving symmetry of equality. Is it possible in scala that you can override equals method of basic types like Int or String? In C++, you can override both operator==(A, int) and operator==(int, A) but it doesn't seem so with java or scala.

Comment: First part IMO is also not easy: `equals` has signature `equals(x: Any): Boolean` and `T` is erased.

Comment: Do you really need `==`? It's easy to define a standalone method in both directions, or define another method implicitly. You can't really override `==` in `Int` as it's already there.

Answer (score 2):

How it can possibly be done with implicits (note that neither `==` nor `equals` can be used here):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

implicit class Wrapper[T : ClassTag](val value: T) {
  def isEqual(other: Any) = other match {
    case x: T => 
      x == value
    case x: Wrapper[T] =>
      x.value == value
    case _ =>
      false
  }
}

5 isEqual (new Wrapper(5)) // true
(new Wrapper(5)) isEqual 5 // true
```